# In the critical strip of Zeta function, the first zero is $\rho=1/2+ 14.1347251417346937904572 i$

Tags: complex-analysis, number-theory

The functional equation of Zeta is $\zeta(s) = 2^s \pi^{s - 1}\cdot \sin\left(\dfrac{\pi s}{2}\right)\cdot \Gamma(1 - s)\cdot\zeta(1 - s)$

My question is that if $\zeta(s)=0$, as below value 
$$s=0.5+14.134725141734693790457251983562470270784257115699243175685567460149$$
 Then $\sin \left(\dfrac{\pi s}{2}\right)$ must be zero, but when I input it in calculator , it show some error.

Is the value of $\sin \left(\dfrac{\pi s}{2}\right)$ is equal to zero or not.

Comment: No, $\sin \pi s/2$ need not be zero. Then zeros of $\zeta(s)$ would not be such a mystery.

Answer (score 1):

When you write 
$$  \zeta(s) = 2^s \pi^{s-1} \sin \frac{\pi s}{2} \Gamma(1-s) \zeta(1-s)  $$
and know the left-hand side is zero, **any** factor on the right can be zero.

For $s$ any zero of $\zeta$ in the critical strip, $\zeta(s) = \zeta(1-s)$.  For zeroes on the critical line, this means that zeros come in pairs, with reflection symmetry through the real axis.

As you can check, $\zeta(1-s)$ for your $s$ is zero.  In fact, for your $s$, \begin{align*}
2^s &= -1.317{\dots} + \mathrm{i}0.514{\dots}, \\
\pi^{s-1} &= -0.502{\dots} - \mathrm{i} 0.256{\dots}, \\
\sin\left( \frac{\pi s}{2} \right) &= 1.552{\dots} \times 10^9 + \mathrm{i} 1.552{\dots} \times 10^9, \\
\Gamma(1-s) &= -1.445{\dots} \times 10^{-10} + \mathrm{i} 5.522{\dots} \times 10^{-10}, \text{ and} \\
\zeta(1-s) &= 0.
\end{align*}

We can also see that the sine term is *never* zero in the critical strip.  Let $x$ and $y$ be real numbers with $0<x<\pi/2$.
$$  \sin(x + \mathrm{i}y) = \sin x \cosh y + \mathrm{i} \cos x \sinh y  \text{.}  $$
We have $\sin x > 0$ for $0<x<\pi/2$ and $\cosh y > 1$ for all $y$.  So the sine factor in the functional equation is never zero in the critical strip (because its real part is never zero).

Comment: Thanks Eric, as you said that zeros come in pair, but my question is that if Zeta is 0, then, is it necessary that sinπs/2 must be 0 or not?

Comment: No.  In fact, the real and imaginary parts of the sine factor for this $s$ are greater than one billion.

Answer (score 1):

To give a more visual display after your comment on Eric Tower's answer:

$$\underbrace{\zeta(s)}_{\text{if } = 0 } = \underbrace{2^s \pi^{s - 1}\cdot \sin\left(\dfrac{\pi s}{2}\right)\cdot \Gamma(1 - s)}_{\text {need not be zero}}\cdot\underbrace{\zeta(1 - s)}_{=0 \\ \text{ by symmetry} \\ \text{ of zeros}}$$